# Alternate formatting of rows, with multiple rows in each set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, alternating

I'm programming in Ruby.

Given that I have the following 2D array:

```
list = [
  ["T1", "Cat 1"],
  ["T2", "Cat 2"],
  ["T3", "Cat 3"],
  ["T4", "Cat 4"],
  ["T5", "Cat 1"],
  ["T6", "Cat 2"],
  ["T7", "Cat 3"],
  ["T8", "Cat 4"],
  ["T9", "Cat 1"],
  ["T10", "Cat 2"],
  ["T11", "Cat 3"],
  ["T12", "Cat 4"],
]
```

I also have a list of categories:

```
cat = ["Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3", "Cat 4"]
cat_count = cat.count
```

I also have the method `bold`, which formats text to be bold, for simplicity here I am going to use the method below:

```
def bold(text)
  'b_' << text
end
```

I would like to format each set of categories, in an alternating fashion. So the first set would be bold, and then the second set not, the third set bold, the fourth set not etc.

In this case I would get out the following formatted output:
**T1
T2
T3
T4**
T5
T6
T7
T8
**T9
T10
T11
T12**

I expect the following ruby output:

```
["b_T1", "Cat 1"]
["b_T2", "Cat 2"]
["b_T3", "Cat 3"]
["b_T4", "Cat 4"]
["T5", "Cat 1"]
["T6", "Cat 2"]
["T7", "Cat 3"]
["T8", "Cat 4"]
["b_T9", "Cat 1"]
["b_T10", "Cat 2"]
["b_T11", "Cat 3"]
["b_T12", "Cat 4"]
```

I have the following code at the moment, which does not look very Rubyist at all. Please help me improve this code.

```
cat_increment = 0
switch = 1

list.map do |l|
  cat_increment+=1
  entry = switch ? [bold(l.first), l.second] : l
  if cat_increment == cat_count
    switch = switch ? nil : 1
    cat_increment = 0
  end 
  entry
end
```

Comment: Not clear how the `cat` array is involved. Is the cycle in `list` fixed? If so, then only the length of the cycle should matter. I don't get why you have that particular `cat` array. Or, it there more to it with `cat`?

Comment: The cycle in list is fixed.

Comment: The car array gives the length of the categories to look for, so that I don' need to do a group_by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/with_index), [array decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) and some math:

```
list.map.with_index do |(title, category), index|
  if index % (2 * cat_count) < cat_count
    [bold(title), category]
  else
    [title, category]
  end
end
```

Comment: sawa's comment to the original question is fair. I assume that you use `cat` to construct the `list`. If so, there might be even better ways of getting where you want. I'll leave that to others, though.

Comment: I am not using cat to construct the list. Both come from other services I do not have control over.

Comment: Also, the list is a gross simplification of a larger 2D array

Comment: OK, then I hope my answer will help :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
enum = [*["b_"]*cat.size, *[""]*cat.size].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["b_", "b_", "b_", "b_", "", "", "", ""]:cycle>
list.map { |t,c| [enum.next+t, c] }
  #=> [["b_T1", "Cat 1"], ["b_T2", "Cat 2"], ["b_T3", "Cat 3"], ["b_T4", "Cat 4"],
  #    ["T5", "Cat 1"], ["T6", "Cat 2"], ["T7", "Cat 3"], ["T8", "Cat 4"],
  #    ["b_T9", "Cat 1"], ["b_T10", "Cat 2"], ["b_T11", "Cat 3"], ["b_T12", "Cat 4"]]
```

[Array#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle) is used to convert the array `["b_", "b_", "b_", "b_", "", "", "", ""]` to an endlessly repeating enumerator.

It is then simply a matter of mapping each element of `list` to a new value in which the "T" string is prepended with the next element of `enum` (`"b_"` or `""`).

I have chosen to use this enumerator to add "T" prefixes that alternate with each group of `cat.size` elements, but the more conventional way is to use indices:

```
list.map.with_index { |(t,c),i| [(i/4).even? ? "b_"+t : "t", c] } 
  #=> [["b_T1", "Cat 1"], ["b_T2", "Cat 2"], ["b_T3", "Cat 3"], ["b_T4", "Cat 4"],
  #    ["T5", "Cat 1"], ["T6", "Cat 2"], ["T7", "Cat 3"], ["T8", "Cat 4"],
  #    ["b_T9", "Cat 1"], ["b_T10", "Cat 2"], ["b_T11", "Cat 3"], ["b_T12", "Cat 4"]]
```

With Ruby 2.3.1 you will be able to write:

```
list.each_with_index { |(t,_),i| print "#{ (i/4).even? ? t.boldify : t } " }
```

<sub>**T1** **T2** **T3** **T4** T5 T6 T7 T8 **T9** **T10** **T11** **T12**</sub>